# Is it possible to use JavaScript to save request (traffic) in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML like this:

```
<ul id="images">
  <li><img src="1.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="2.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="3.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="4.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="5.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="6.png" /></li>
</ul>
<script>
$("ul#images > li").each(function(i){
   // let's randomly pick up one picture.
   if ( i == Math.random()*6 ) {
      $(this).remove();
   }
})
</script>
```

I only need to display one random picture for one time. Is it possible to prevent the image from loading by only JavaScript? I can't modify the HTML part.

Comment: Did you try to set the _img src_ to blank?

Comment: @AhsN he can't  modify the HTML part.

Comment: By the time your JavaScript has run your browser has already requested the images.

Comment: so unless I modify the HTML part (like remove the `src` before anything happen), there's nothing I can do?

Comment: If the html has already run by the time your scripts runs then they have already started downloading.